# How does background data transfer work?

Tags: android

I have a problem understanding how the 'Restrict background data' setting in Android really works. I always thought that with this restriction turned on, only visible applications could download data, but currently I'm developing an application that has shaken this understanding... My application registers an alarm in AlarmService to start a background IntentService every 5 minutes. This service will then download the latest financial quotes. What is surprising to me, is that no matter what the 'Restrict background data' setting is, the service is able to download the data over WIFI (didn't try with cellular interface yet).

So my question is, how does 'Restrict background data' setting in Android really work? Also should I worry about it in the case of my application and are there any differences in the behaviour of this option depending on the version of Android (I've checked on 2.3.3 Samsung Galaxy SII)?

Answer (score 2):

> how does 'Restrict background data' setting in Android really work?

For Android 1.x/2.x/3.x, it was an "opt-in" setting for developers. Developers should check to see if background data is disallowed and not do it in the background if it is.

For Android 4.0+, Android basically blocks you from doing Internet access if the user's profile for your app calls for that (e.g., you have exceeded an allotted bandwidth threshold).

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. I'll do some tests on Android 2.x/3.x/4.x emulator and see how my app behaves there.

Answer (score 1):

For Ice Cream Sandwich it specifically says that the restrict background option is for data only and does not restrict for WiFi.